# Can you override system.serviceModel configuration section?

Tags: .net, wcf, app-config, configurationsection

We are trying to create a "proxy" class that would serve the WCF service with its configuration properties.

Because we can't store those properties in the app.config file, i'm looking for a way to "proxy" it out and use custom configurationSection which would provide all these data upon request. In order to do so, i would need to tell the .NET framework to load system.serviceModel using my own ConfigurationSection, and i'm not sure i can do it.

If anyone can either approve my assumption, or even better, provide me with an idea how can i WCF configuration settings using another source, that would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're looking for the way to create and register your wcf service in code pls check the code below for an example:

below is a method to create the service host object:

```
public static ServiceHost RegisterService<T>(object service, int port, string serviceName)
{
    // Returns a list of ipaddress configuration
    IPHostEntry ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

    // Select the first entry. I hope it's this maschines IP
    IPAddress ipAddress = ips.AddressList[0];

    // Create the url that is needed to specify where the service should be started
    string urlService = "net.tcp://" + ipAddress.ToString() + String.Format(":{0}/{1}", port, serviceName);

    // Instruct the ServiceHost that the type that is used is a ServiceLibrary.service1
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(service);
    // define events if needed
    //host.Opening += new EventHandler(HostOpeningEvent);
    //host.Opened += new EventHandler(HostOpenedEvent);
    //host.Closing += new EventHandler(HostClosingEvent);
    //host.Closed += new EventHandler(HostClosedEvent);

    // The binding is where we can choose what transport layer we want to use. HTTP, TCP ect.
    NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
    tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; 

    // Add a endpoint
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(T), tcpBinding, urlService);

    // A channel to describe the service. Used with the proxy scvutil.exe tool
    ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
    metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (metadataBehavior == null)
    {
        string httpURL = "http://" + ipAddress.ToString() + String.Format(":{0}/{1}", port + 1, serviceName);

        // This is how I create the proxy object that is generated via the svcutil.exe tool
        metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(httpURL);
        metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        metadataBehavior.ToString();
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
    }
    return host;
}
```

here's how you can use it:

```
ServiceHost host = RegisterService<your_service_interface>(your_service, port, "yout_service_name");
host.Open();
```

hope this helps, regards